# Excel Application.OnTime additional time delay

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a macro to run a web query every 30 minutes. It takes about 45-75 seconds to fetch data from website. Basically it is working fine with a small problem. I first start it at 9:00am manually. It takes about 1 min to complete. Then it works again on 9:31, 10:01, 10:31, 11:02 etc. I want it should be 9:00, 9:30, 10:00 etc. I also need it to start automatically at 9:00 am if file is already open. I am using the following code:

```
Sub RefreshAll()
    Call macro1
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:30:00"), "RefreshAll"
End Sub

Sub macro1()
    'web query code here
End Sub
```

Please suggest something.

Comment: Move the `Call macro1` to the 2nd line and have the `Application.OnTime` run first?

Comment: Thank you BigBen. It works fine with your suggestion. Please also tell me about how to start it at 9:00 automatically if file is already open.

Comment: You can have an `Application.OnTime` within the `Workbook_Open` event... but that won't guarantee it runs every day at 9:00 if it's already open, unless you're manually opening the file every day before 9:00. I'd use Task Schedule and a script to guarantee it runs, but would need more detail about when you open/close the file.

Comment: I open the excel file at 8:30 and start the 1st macro manually. Now it will start 2nd macro to fetch data at 9:00 with the following code: Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:00:00"), "macro1". My problem is how to combine it with my original code to repeat it every 30 minutes.

Comment: If you're opening the workbook manually at 8:30, then use `Application.OnTime` within the `Workbook_Open` event.

Comment: Workbook open time is not exact 8:30, it may be 8:35 or any time before 9:00.

Comment: `Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:00:00"), "RefreshAll"`. Add that within the `Workbook_Open` event.

Comment: Thank you again BigBen. You have solved my both issues. Please tell me how to close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the schedule to be 9:00, 9:30, and so on, move the `Application.OnTime` call to the first line:

   ```
   Sub RefreshAll()
       Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:30:00"), "RefreshAll"
       Call macro1
   End Sub
   ```
2. To have `RefreshAll` run automatically at 9:00 (if you are opening the workbook manually before):

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:00:00"), "RefreshAll"
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Either run `Application.OnTime` before you call `macro1` as @BigBen suggested, or another approach would be to write the start time of the macro into a variable. So no matter how long `macro1` takes to proceed it will use the start time `9:00` + 30 min.

Then check if your `macro1` run successfully and if so set the `OnTime`.
This way it won't set the `OnTime` if fetching the data failed.

```
Sub RefreshAll()
    Dim StartTime As date
    StartTime = Now 'remember the start time of the macro = 9:00

    If macro1 Then 'run macro1 and check if it returned true
        Application.OnTime StartTime + TimeValue("00:30:00"), "RefreshAll"
    End If
End Sub

Function macro1() As Boolean
    On Error Goto ERR_HANDLING

    'web query code here

ERR_HANDLING:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        macro1 = True 'return true if no errors
    Else
        MsgBox "Could not fetch data"
    End If
End Function
```

If there is the possibility that the runtime of `macro1` exceeds the `TimeValue` that you add, you should check for that like

```
    If macro1 Then 'run macro1 and check if it returned true
        If StartTime + TimeValue("00:30:00") > Now Then
            Application.OnTime StartTime + TimeValue("00:30:00"), "RefreshAll"
        Else
            MsgBox "Could not set OnTime because it was in the past."
        End If
    End If
```